# Is there good software for recovering photos from an iphone data

Tags: ios

My iPhone is in recovery mode and I want to recover some photos. Does anyone know if dr.fone works? I don't want to pay for something that doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try iTools Pro (google it). It recovered my photos (but I only had 55 so I don't know if there is a maximum it will do for free).

Is your phone stuck in Recovery Mode?

Comment: Dr Fone will kick the iPhone out of Recovery Mode if that is all you need.

Comment: It is stuck in recovery mode and gets error occurred (9) when I attempt to update the software in iTunes.

Comment: Looks like iTools is a window program. I have a Mac.

Comment: iTools has both a Windows and a Mac version. On http://sale.itools.cn/ you will find the Mac version of iTools (actually iTools Pro). The trial version will kick your iPhone out of Recovery Mode. So will Dr. Fone.

Comment: Ultimately I decided that the phone was not repairable. And the programs I investigated would not recover photos without pay. Thanks for the suggestions